# Limit in $S' (\mathbb{R})$

Tags: limits, distribution-theory

Given the sequence of distributions: 
$$
x^3~ \sin (nx),~~n \in  (\mathbb{N}) $$
How can i find the limit for $n \rightarrow \infty$?

I tried with the usual substitution $y=nx$, but it leads to integrals that don't converge.

Using instead the Riemann-Lebesgue theorem, i get that the limit is zero, but I don't think this is the right answer (Wolfram alpha says that, in the sense of functions, the limit is $x^3 -1$). Am I missing something? Why can't i use the Riemann-Lebesgue theorem?

Comment: Using Riemann-Lebesgue is okay and indeed gives the result 0. I also calculated it this way. What do you mean by this limit "in the sense of functions"?

Comment: Could you show what you wrote on Wolfram?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+n-%3E+inf++%28x%5E3%29*%28+sin%28nx%29%29

Comment: Since $x^3 ~ sin(nx)$ is also a function in $\mathbb{R}$, I think Wolfram alpha treats it as a function, and gives the limit in $L_{\infty}$; this is however an odd result in my opinion, but since I don't know the subject I'll stop here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We indeed obtain that the limiting distribution is $0$ because $x\mapsto x^3\varphi(x)$ is a smooth integrable function with integrable derivative. So Riemann-Lebesgue lemma applies.